# Reading Avro Protocol (avpr) file in C++

Tags: apache, rpc, avro

I am building an RPC application, with clients in Java, C# and C++.
I wrote an Avro protocol file (.avpr) and can read the protocol in Java and C#.

How do I use this protocol file to generate code in C++?
(Can you even use an AVPR file in C++?)

Additional info: Doing a precompile to a flat file in C++ as described in the avro docs, gives an  error:
Failed to parse or compile schema: Missing Json field "type": {"messages":{"...

Comment: What files do you think cannot be read in C++?

Comment: @AlexisWilke, I am basically looking for a RPC client implementation in C++. I am a bit confused by the opposing documentation that I read on the avro site.
The wiki site [(link)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AVRO/Supported+Languages) says RPC is supported in C++, however the Avro C++ language page says there is no support for Avro RPC [(link)](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/api/cpp/html/index.html)